# TypeScript type predicate or throw

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is there a way to write a function with type predicate that throws instead of returning `false` and returns void (`undefined`) istead of `true`? Something like this, which doesn't compile:

```js
function assertString(value: unknown): value extends string ? void : never {
  if (typeof value !== 'string') {
    throw new Error('string expected');
  }
}
```

"boolean" version is simple, but not what I need:

```js
function isString(value: unknown): value is string {
  return typeof value === 'string';
}
```

Comment: TS does not support conditional types in a place of return type. However it works if you overload your function. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/w1PkAW). Apart from that, if you want to create assert function with throwing an error you should consider @TobiasS. 's solution

Comment: @TobiasS. thank you! I did not know about `asserts` keyword. You actually answered my question.